# Symfony & TWIG: Route for Template directory not working fine

Tags: symfony, routes, directory, twig

I'm new to Symfony and I have created many twig html templates and this function to route in my Controller:

```
      /**
      * @Route("/{path}")
      */
      public function renderTemplate($path) {
        return $this->render('/'.$path.'/index.html.twig');
      }
      ?>
```

The renderTemplate() function works fine for all first level folders, but not for subdirectory files, because it seems like it interrups after a "/". I don't want to write dozens of new Route functions.

How can I implement all sites including subdirectories separated by "/"?

What is a safe practice and easy solution?

The structure of my twig templates folder is this:
[Templates folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5iby.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer to be [here in the Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/slash_in_parameter.html).

Apparently, you can allow "/" in your variable like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class DefaultController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/share/{token}", name="share", requirements={"token"=".+"})
     */
    public function share($token)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I named all my twig templates "index.html.twig" and put them in the corresponding file path in my templates folder and now my function is working very smoothly for every site.

I may have to change it later to do individual requests, but it was a convienient short-term solution to be able to see all my pages with easy and nice-looking links and only one route function in my controller.

Answer (score 2):

`@Route`is your URL, not your file path.
The default path in Symfony (3.4) is `app/Ressources/view/`

Thus, if you want to reach `app/Ressources/view/default/index.html.twig`, you will do this:

```
return $this->render('default/index.html.twig');
```